# shared host and schedule:run laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have shared host and I want to run my schedule. but I dont know how to set address from my cpanel.

this it my schedule:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Jobs\SendOrdersResultNotification;
use App\Order;
use App\RequestForBarber;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        '\App\Console\Commands\GetBarbers',
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function (){
            $requests=RequestForBarber::where('flag','=',1)->get();
            foreach ($requests as $request){
                RequestForBarber::destroy($request->id);
            }
        })->hourly();

    }


    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

depending on the above documentation I don't know how I set to cron inside cpanel.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAu56.png)

Comment: Depends on your version of cPanel, but it should have an option in the Advanced view for setting a cron job, look [here](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/74Docs/Cron+Jobs).

Comment: Your question here is not related to Laravel but to server administration. I guess it suits better into [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).